# Can Insert Object > Text from File use a relative path instead of an absolute path?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365, sharepoint

Problem: I am building training documentation for a client. The client has multiple roles that need to perform the same task. However, for each role there must be a distinct job aid or training manual. The content also changes with relative frequency, so it is important that all the duplicated information remain up to date. Copying and pasting changes across documents is inefficient and can lead to errors.

Proposed solution: I have created a master document with all training content. I have bookmarked all of the training materials. **I have inserted the bookmarks as links into the appropriate documents**. Now I have **one source of truth that can be updated**, and **changes will be reflected in all documents with a quick field update**.

Where I need help: All of this works great until I need to copy it from my company's sharepoint to the client's sharepoint (or even move it between directories on my own company's sharepoint). All of the links break because inserting object > text from file uses absolute paths. **Is it possible to use a relative path to insert objects?** Also, if I'm way off base here, please let me know if there's another solution.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done but requires editing each link field. The process is set forth in Paul Edstein's tutorial on [Word Fields and Relative Paths to External Files](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html).

> Word tends to store paths to external files with absolute paths. The
> fields affected by this include Word's DATABASE, INCLUDEPICTURE,
> INCLUDETEXT, LINK, RD and HYPERLINK fields. This means that, should
> you need to move the files as a group to another folder (eg putting
> them on a CD or USB stick for portability), all the links will break.
> What is needed is a means of coercing Word into applying some sort of
> relative path addressing for fields pointing to other files. Even if
> you omit the path from the field code, in most Word versions it still
> gets stored in the file's metadata. The only version I know of that
> doesn't always do this is Word 2010 - and even that seems to vary
> according to whether the path has ever been stored...
>
> Well, there is a solution (based on an idea originally developed by
> Peter Jamieson, another MS Word MVP) that works with DATABASE,
> INCLUDEPICTURE, INCLUDETEXT, RD and HYPERLINK fields, but not with
> LINK fields. For LINK fields, scroll to the bottom of this thread. The
> following example employs an INCLUDEPICTURE field, but works equally
> well with DATABASE, INCLUDETEXT, RD and HYPERLINK fields.

---

> To make the INCLUDEPICTURE field look in the current folder, cut &
> paste the FILENAME field into it, replacing the document path and
> inserting '\..\' or '/ /' between that and the hyperlink file's
> name, thus: {INCLUDEPICTURE "{FILENAME \p}/../Image.png"} or
> {INCLUDEPICTURE "{FILENAME \p}\..\Image.png"}
>
> How this works: The FILENAME p field extracts the current file's name
> and path. The following '\..\' or '/../' tells Word to ignore the
> filename and get just the path. Then all you need to do is to add the
> source file's name & extension.
>
> The same approach can be extended to implement a form of relative
> addressing. For example: {INCLUDEPICTURE "{FILENAME \p}\..\My
> Pictures\Image.png"} looks in the child folder named 'My Pictures'
> and: {INCLUDEPICTURE "{FILENAME \p}\..\..\Image.png"} looks in the
> parent folder, while: {INCLUDEPICTURE "{FILENAME \p}\..\..\My
> Pictures\Image.png"} looks in the parent folder, then its child
> folder named 'My Pictures' (a sibling folder, so to speak).

The [original tutorial](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html) includes a helpful macro and more of a breakdown on what is being done.